# Can I get Select box value from given select box text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can I get Select box value from given select box text ? Need help

```
<select id='list'>
<option value='1'>Option A</option>
<option value='2'>Option B</option>
<option value='3'>Option C</option>
</select>

$("#list[text='Option B']").val();
```

Comment: i want that select box value but i have the text only :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use filter:

```
$("#list option").filter(function(){
     return $(this).text().trim() == 'Option B';
}).val();
```

You could also use `$("#list option:contains(Option B)")`, but it would bring multiple results in your case.

Comment: This is the best answer, more exact than using `:contains`

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$("#list option:contains(Option B)").val();
```

---

Edit, Updated

As pointed out by @dfsq , commenting on original answer

> Not very reliable, as it will also much "Option Boom". filter might be
>   better option.

tests http://jsfiddle.net/5cy9tt2o/1/

Additionally,

> because `:contains` selector just checks `indexOf` for occurrences. See
>   the source of it [here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.expr.filters.contains). ... usually it's not a problem, just > something to be aware of.

where *"`:contains` selector just checks `indexOf` for occurrences"* does not appear at [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) ?

---

Utilizing `.filter()` may also return "unreliable" results if a particular match is found, or not found , by the provided match to search for within the given element text.

For example, @dfsq provided the example of

```
$("#list option:contains(Option B)").val();
```

matching

```
"Option Boom"
```

The accepted answer , though utilizing `.filter()` may not return expected results if `" "` appeared after `text`

```
<option value='2'>Option B </option>
```

tests http://jsfiddle.net/5cy9tt2o/4/

---

An alternative approach, which should be expected to return exact match , without calling addition internal methods ; though passing `RegExp` parameters, or any other settings , could , of course, be optional.

Basic and primary focus of method to return exact match, if that is possible, of text passed to the method.

Given `html` from original post, modified with same test conditions tried at above,

```
<select id='list'>
<option value='1'>Option Boom</option>
<option value='2'>Option B</option>
<option value='3'>Option C </option>
</select>
```

js

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.tryToMatchExactText = function (text) {
    return $("*").filter(function(i, el) {
      return el.textContent.match(new RegExp("^"+text+"$")) !== null
    })
  };
}(jQuery));

var list = $("#list option");

console.log(list.tryToMatchExactText("Option B").val() // `"2"`
       , list.tryToMatchExactText("Option Boom").val() // `"1"`
       , list.tryToMatchExactText("Option C").val() // `undefined`
       , list.tryToMatchExactText("Option C ").val() // `"3"`
);
```

tests http://jsfiddle.net/5cy9tt2o/3/

Comment: Not very reliable, as it will also much "Option Boom". `filter` might be better option.

Comment: @dfsq In practice that's not usually a problem.

Comment: @dfsq Interesting. Aware if that is expected result by design ? , aware of stackoverflow questions , documentation relating to this ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, because `:contains` selector just checks `indexOf` for occurrences. See the source of it [here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.expr.filters.contains). But as Barmar said, usually it's not a problem, just something to be aware of.

Comment: @dfsq _"because :contains selector just checks indexOf for occurrences."_ Cannot seem to fathom why this detail would _not_ be in documentation http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ ? Quick differentiation , "fix"; though could perhaps achieve without call to jQuery version of `.filter()` http://jsfiddle.net/5cy9tt2o/3/ ?

Comment: I guess, `:contains` implies that it checks for any substring occurrence. If exact equality is needed it's better to simply use filter.

Comment: @dfsq Yes, you are correct. Extra wrapper of `$.fn` not needed. Thanks:), Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Go For :

```
$("#list").children().eq(2).val();
```

Comment: If he knew which option it was, he could just use `2`, he wouldn't have to search for the matching text.

Comment: @Barmar You'r right ! So i guess .filter() is the good answer here.